# Git Forensics is failing to install some of it dependencies in Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I am trying to install the plugin [Git Forensics plugin](https://plugins.jenkins.io/git-forensics/#dependencies) in Jenkins for visualization of Git commits for last six months but it is not installing all the dependent plugins. Tried multiple times.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Per comments in answer, pls review [How do I ask a good question? ](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

Since there is no obvious issue regarding [Git Forensics Jenkins plugin issues](https://issues.jenkins.io/browse/JENKINS-64862?jql=component%3D25321%20AND%20text%20%7E%20install), check:

- your Jenkins version
- Your Jenkins plugin page to see if there is any incompatibility warning regarding the plugin itself
- Your Jenkins logs

The idea is to check if the installation process leaves any trace which could explain what is missing.

Comment: To add to the list, impossible to say w/o more info, but perhaps update site is improperly configured, or not reachable due to proxy or firewall issues.

Comment: @IanW Good point. Let us wait for any updates from the OP.